# How to use multiple pasteboards in OS X?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I have a situation where I need 2 or 3 different pasteboards so that I can issue a command-c/v for the traditional copy/paste and then be able to use option-command-c/v for a secondary pasteboard copy and paste and then a third one as well if possible.

The usecase is such that I need to rapidly be able to copy and paste different patterns in a dynamic manner.

I own [PTHPasteboard Pro](http://www.pth.com) which seems to work again nicely in 10.11, but I have not been able to find a way to copy into additional pasteboards that you can create with it... only paste out from it.

Any ideas on how to either use this app or another option to implement additional pasteboards?

Answer (score 1):

### PTHPasteboard and OS X 10.10+

The [PTH web site](http://www.pth.com/) suggests PTHPasteboard Pro does not work on OS X 10.10 or later:

> PTHPasteboard is not currently available for sale, due to incompatibility with Mac OS X 10.10.

Thus it is probable there is no way to copy into additional pasteboards PTHPasteboard creates on OS X 10.11.

#### Alternatives

Alternatives listed on [PTHPasteboard Pro's MacUpdate page](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/17465/pthpasteboard-pro) include:

- [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com)
- [Clipboard Evolved](http://www.machsoftwaredesign.com/clipboard.html)

Regrettably, the alternatives above do not mention OS X 10.11 support. Comments on MacUpdate suggest they may still work on the latest OS X.

Comment: Well the interesting thing is that everything seems to work great on 10.11, except being able to copy into ancillary pasteboards aside from `Main`...  No problems otherwise with the app.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Keyboard Maestro.  It includes a  clipboard history switcher. 
https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/

includes a free trail

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sad to hear this tool has been discontinued. I'm still using it on 10.13 with no adverse consequences at all.

I have never "copied" things into the secondary pasteboards, I have always "added" things there. You click the pencil icon on the pasteboard, then the + button, then add a clipping (you can paste one in as you would paste anything anywhere else). It stays permanently until you remove it manually.